# Select multiple table without AS (alias)?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to SELECT from more than one table that has a lot of fields. Do I have to manually fabricate the query like this:

```
table1.field1 AS table1_field1, table1.field2 AS table1_field2, ..., table2.field1 AS table2_field1, ...
```

Or is there any workaround for this in MySQL or PHP that will automatically take care of all these when there are identical field names in the tables?

In PHP, I tried:

```
$results = $conn -> query("SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1, table2 WHERE 1"); // $conn is a mysqli object
$results = $results -> fetch_array();
```

But if there is a field named 'title' in both of the 2 tables, $results['title'] would just contain the value of the record from the 2nd table.

I know there are numeric indexes that you can use to access the value but:

1. It's unreadable.
2. You have to update the code accordingly every time the table structure such as the order of the fields changes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are workarounds.
mysql and mysqli extensions, as well as certain pdo drivers, have functions to let you get at column meta data. Heres a pdo sample

```
$stmt->execute();
$qualifiedColumnNames = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $columnMeta = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    $qualifiedColumnNames[] = "$columnMeta[table].$columnMeta[name]";
}

print_r(array_combine($qualifiedColumnNames, $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)));
```

So you can use table1.* and be able to differentiate conflicting column names.

Also, another trick that works because the column order in the result set is deterministic.

```
select 'table1' table_sep1
       table1.*
       'table1' table_sep2
       table2.*
```

I'll leave the code up to you, but you can fetch a row as an array, and loop through the array keys. Since they will be in order, you can assume each column that follows a table separator column belongs to the table specified by the separator, until you come across the next sep.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that you only need to alias the fields with names that occur in both tables and even then you only need to alias the second column.  Also, if you only want the field from one of the tables, you can include only that one in the list of fields to retrieve.  Finally, you can alias each table name itself with a shorter name which can then be used in the column aliases.

So, all told, you can do something like:

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t2.title as second_title, t2.somethingelse
    FROM  table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no convention in SQL to dynamically generate column aliases.  If you need them, you need to define them -- one by one.

Comment: MySQL works properly by returning all the values of all the fields even if there are identical field names. However PHP seems to overwrite everything that has the same field name (array index), because $results -> fetch_array() always returns an array THUS values are overwritten by the same index (field name).

Is there any way to work around this in PHP?

Comment: @kavoir.com: Yes, SQL supports columns from different tables with identical names *as long as there's a table name or alias reference attached to them* -- otherwise you'll get an "ambiguous column reference" error.  I'm not strong in PHP, but it's going to depend on what SQL/MySQL supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over numeric indexes and check each index for name:

```
$result = mysql_query('select t1.*, t2.* from t1, t2');
$num = mysql_num_fields($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $column_name = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
}
```

If you *really* need it, this could be a dirty workaround to distinguish which table you are in while iterating above: `select 1 as _t1_, t1.*, 1 as _t2_, t2.* from t1, t2`. Dummy columns indicating where table columns begin.